# "Delegated to" vs. "Assigned to"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

What is the differences in these terms. I want to use one of them in Task management software. Which term is better for the menu meaning "List of task that was delegated|assigned to me" and "List of tasks that I have delegated to someone else".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Delegated" carries with it the connotation that one is acting as a representative of a superior in carrying out a task. "Assigned" merely means told to do a task.

If I were your superior, I could delegate you to carry out one of my tasks, or assign you a task of your own level.

Comment: Good point of view to my particular question. Thanks. A little clarification: if you assign task you don't care about its future, it's not your task, it's task of who you assign to; if you delegate a task to someone it is still your task in your tasklist, you simply "ask someone to do it"; right?

Comment: @Vladimir: I don't agree that if you assign a task you don't care about its completion. If I were to assign you the task of unblocking the toilet, I might care a great deal whether you completed it or not. Especially if I really have to go.

Comment: yeah, I mean you don't care about process of working on this task. If you have to visit toilet when it is unblocked it's another task. In my app I'll create ability to tell the system to create a new task when task that you are going to assign to someone else is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Would not something like "My tasks" be better? This may sound like a cliché, but enables you to escape the above dilemma?